# Why this two codes have differences?

Tags: react-native

In react-native, in .js file
When I run first image of codes,
there aren't any errors.
but When I run second image of codes, there is errors of "undefined is not a function(evaluating 'React.createClass')
I copy codes of second image in others blog, but that can't running.
Why this two codes have differences?(one hasn't error, the other has error)

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyCmV.png)

[Seconde image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvB7u.png)

What are the differences between variable var and import?

Comment: Can you provide your code which has errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From react-native version 0.25 onwards, Requiring React API from react-native is deprecated.

The difference is also in using ES6(ES2015) javascript and ES5 javascript syntax

1.react-native version > 0.25

```
//ES6 (ES2015) javascript syntax
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

//ES5 javascript syntax
var React = require('react');
var Component = React.Component;
```

2.react-native version < 0.25

```
//ES6 (ES2015) javascript syntax
import React, { Component, View } from 'react-native';

//ES5 javascript syntax
var React = require('react-native');
var Component = React.Component;
var View = React.View;
```

Comment: In first image, variable is import , in the second image, variable is var
this is .js file why var doesn't work?

Comment: your answer means that because of the version differences there is different require syntax so in latest version requires import ~~ not var ~~ ?

Comment: No. You can use both syntaxes. The main difference how you import React,Component module. Previously they were inside react-native. Now react-native depends on react package for that.  It is better aligned with the philosophy is that react component model is render target independent.